# How can I get arrows at the end of x-axis and y-axis using highcharts.js?

Tags: javascript, highcharts, bubble-chart

[image]

I want to get some arrows like the picture above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can render you own shapes and lay them on top of axis lines. Rendering custom shapes can be achieved via [renderer](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Renderer).

You can also [extend Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts) in a way that the method responsible for rendering an axis line will be changed.

A simplified extension could look like this:

```
  Highcharts.wrap(Highcharts.Axis.prototype, 'getLinePath', function(p, lineWidth) {
var linePath = p.call(this, lineWidth);

if (this.options.arrowOnEnd) {
  var arrowFactor = 20,
    x,
    y,
    arrowPath,
    newPath;

  if (this.horiz) {
    x = linePath[4] = linePath[4] - arrowFactor;
    y = linePath[5];

    arrowPath = [
      'L', x - 0.35 * arrowFactor, y - 0.35 * arrowFactor,
      'L', x + 1 * arrowFactor, y,
      'L', x - 0.35 * arrowFactor, y + 0.35 * arrowFactor,
      'L', x, y
    ];
    newPath = linePath.concat(arrowPath);
  } else {
    x = linePath[1];
    y = linePath[2] = linePath[2]; // + arrowFactor;

    arrowPath = [
      'M', x, y,
      'L', x - 0.35 * arrowFactor, y + 0.35 * arrowFactor,
      'L', x, y - 1 * arrowFactor,
      'L', x + 0.35 * arrowFactor, y + 0.35 * arrowFactor,
      'L', x, y
    ];

    newPath = arrowPath.concat(linePath);
  }

  return newPath;
}

return linePath;
});
```

CSS for filling the arrows:

```
.highcharts-axis-line {
  fill: black;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
}
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/z2aagpeu/